# Proof Verification - Archimedean Property

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I am self-learning real analysis and learning to write proofs. I am trying to prove the Archimedean Property and would like to check if my attempt at a proof is correct and how to improve my proof writing skills.

> Given any number $x\in R$, there exists an $n \in N$ satisfying $n>x$.

My understanding of this statement is that the set of natural numbers $N$ is not bounded above.

(Proof): By contradiction, there exists an $x\in R$,such that $\forall n \in N$,$n \leq x$. $x$ is an upper bound for $N$, so by the Axiom of Completeness $N$ has a least upper bound $\alpha = sup (N)$.

By the approximation property, if $\alpha = sup (N)$ then $\forall \epsilon >0$ ,$\exists n \in N$ such that $\alpha - \epsilon < n \leq \alpha$
$\implies \alpha - \epsilon < n$

$\implies \alpha < n +\epsilon$

$\implies \alpha \leq n$

$\implies n \geq \alpha$ which contradicts that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound.

Comment: (There exists some  $x\in\mathbb R $ such that  $n\leq x $ for all $n\in\mathbb N $.)

Comment: Thank you I made the correction.

Comment: Still not correct.

Comment: Why is $n \ge \alpha =\sup \mathbb N$ a contradiction that $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of $N$?  You haven't found an upper bound that is smaller than $\alpha$. And you havent found an integer that is larger than $\alpha$.  So nothing has been contradicted.

Comment: So either try to find a $\beta < \alpha$ were $\beta$ is an upper bound.  (That would be a contradiction).  Or try to find an $m\in \mathbb N$ so that $m > \alpha$.  (That would be a contradiction.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a mistake.

Let $\alpha = \sup(\mathbb{N})$ which exists by the reasons you mentiond. It is true that this means that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha-\varepsilon <n\leq \alpha$.

From this you conclude that $\alpha<n+\varepsilon$ which is fine.

**However** this does not mean that $\alpha\leq n$.

You can't deduce that because $n$ depends on $\varepsilon$, therefore the usual trick of letting $\varepsilon  = (n-\alpha)/2$ isn't possible (you can't define $\varepsilon$ using a variable $n$ which depends on $\varepsilon$).

Instead you should fix $\varepsilon$. If you choose $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, then $\alpha<n+\frac{1}{2}$ for some natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$ which corresponds to $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$. From this you can conclude that $\alpha<n+1$, since $n+1$ is a natural number we get a contradiction to the fact that $\alpha$ is an upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

Two mistakes.

For all $\epsilon > 0$ the will indeed exist an $n_\epsilon\in \mathbb N$ so that $\alpha -\epsilon < n_\epsilon \le \alpha$ and $n_\epsilon < \alpha +\epsilon$ but that does not mean $n_\epsilon < \alpha + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.

$n_\epsilon < \alpha + \epsilon$ is only true for *that* $n_\epsilon$ and *that* $\epsilon$.  For a *different* value of $\delta > 0$ it will follow that that is an $n_\delta$ so that $n_\delta < \alpha + \delta$ but $n_\delta$ could be a completely different value than $n_\epsilon$.

Second.

$n\ge \alpha$ does not contradict that $\alpha$ is a least upper bound.  $\alpha$ is a least upper bound, and $n \in \mathbb N$ will mean that $\alpha \ge n$ and we have $n \ge \alpha$.   That's not a contradiction.

......

So here's a hint.

let $0 < \epsilon <1$.

Let $n_\epsilon$ but the natural number where $\alpha - \epsilon < n_\epsilon \le \alpha$.

Now I'll tell you right off the bat, you will never find a contradiction with $n_\epsilon$.  You can note that $n_\epsilon < \alpha+\epsilon$ if you want but that won't be a contradiction nor will it help you.

You will find nothing wrong with $n_\epsilon$.

Try to find a *different* natural number that does cause a contradiction.

Second hint.  Don't bother trying to find a different $\delta > 0$ and a different $n_\delta$ so that $\alpha - \delta < n_\delta \le \alpha$.  If you do that you will find something very important about $n_\epsilon$ vs. $n_\delta$ but it *won't* be a contradiction.

Third hint:  You have $\alpha -\epsilon < n_\epsilon \le \alpha$.  Try to find an $m\in \mathbb N$ so that $m > \alpha$.  That was your original goal after all.  How does knowing $\alpha - \epsilon < n_\epsilon \le \alpha$ help you find $m$ so that $m > \alpha$?

=====

Fourth Hint:  FORGET ANALYSIS!  How would a five year old answer answer this?

Try it.  Go up to a five year old and ask her "I'm thinking of a real big number.  How do you know that there is a bigger one?"  I bet you she will say the answer that is the utter *key* to this proof!